# Apache Alias .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm not very savvy with Apache and have put my best efforts forward to understand the documentation; the issue is the following:

Path to files

```
my.website.com/untouchable/cms/{any file}
```

Needs to be same as

```
my.website.com/untouchable/{any file}
```

I can only edit the .htaccess inside the untouchable folder; I have tried using RewriteBase but is not yielding desired result. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Why not just move your app to the untouchable folder instead?

Comment: @PanamaJack I could do this, but was wanting to be able to easily migrate the site to a different folder when needed since what is in the cms folder will be available for short time. Thought this would be an easy clean way to do it.